# PHP - Image Shortcut

Tags: php, image, seo, alias, shortcut

I have an image called *example.jpg*.
My site has 3 languages and i need the same image, but with different names (one for language).
So, for example i need:
example.jpg
esempio.jpg
ejemplo.jpg
The image should be only one.

Is there a way to create an "alias" of the image?

Comment: Store the aliases in a database table?

Comment: i would like to reach the image via absolute link.
www.mysite.com/example.jpg
www.mysite.com/esempio.jpg
www.mysite.com/ejemplo.jpg

Comment: You can't just use the English name? The user would only see it if they look at the source or the image properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use the image in a img tag, you don't need to change their name according to the SEO (if it is what you want to accomplish, your description is a little lacking). If it is the correct scenario, you can just stick with an english name for the images and use the tag "alt" to describe it in different language, like that:

```
<img src="example.jpg" alt="example"/>
<img src="example.jpg" alt="esempio"/>
<img src="example.jpg" alt="ejemplo"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what platform you're on, the answer may differ... But one option may be to create a symbolic link.  In *nix environments you can create a symlink like so:

```
ln -s /path/to/original.jpg /path/to/alias.jpg
```